# If Statement that Tests Multiple Ternary Operators Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering why my solution doesn't work. I have the following:

```
//tells if type should be included in the row data
isInReport = {factual: true, eac: false, variance: false}

//report has hundreds of objects, each with a type of either Plan, Factual, EAC, Variance
report = [{type: "Plan"}, {type: "Factual"}, {type: "EAC"}, {type: "Variance"}];
```

I need to loop through the report array, and do something always if item.type is "Plan," or if it is one of the other 3 types, but only if it is true in the isInReport object. So in my example the if statement should pass if item.type is "Plan," or "Factual"

Why doesn't this code work? The logic seems right to me even if a little odd. When I've tested it always returns all types no matter what. Thanks for any help!

```
report.map(function (item) {
  if (
  item.type === "Plan" ||
  item.type === (isInReport.factual) ? "Factual" : "Plan" ||
  item.type === (isInReport.eac) ? "EAC" : "Plan" ||
  item.type === (isInReport.variance) ? "Variance" : "Plan"
  ) {
   //do stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: Maybe you need `report.filter` instead or in addition?

Comment: Can you recheck if the line `report = [{type: "Plan"}{type: "Factual"}{type: "EAC"}{type: "Variance"}];` is correct? A lot of commas appear to be missing, such as: `report = [{type: "Plan"},{type: "Factual"},{type: "EAC"},{type: "Variance"}];` Also, can you confirm that `item.type === "Plan"` yelding true, [no more checks are needed, since the statement is already truth-ish](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Truthy)

Comment: Not sure what is your question here, anyway even this code work if you can change it, it should be good to change it in a form that is much readable. You don't need the ternary operator inside an *if* condition!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you want to do:

```
if ( item.type === "Plan" || isInReport[ item.type.toLowerCase() ] ) {
    //do stuff
}
```

There is a comment suggesting this is not correct.  Can you confirm what you expect as a result for the 4 items in **report**?

```js
//tells if type should be included in the row data
isInReport = {factual: true, eac: false, variance: false}

//report has hundreds of objects, each with a type of either Plan, Factual, EAC, Variance
report = [{type: "Plan"}, {type: "Factual"}, {type: "EAC"}, {type: "Variance"}];

report.forEach(function(item){
  if ( item.type === "Plan" || isInReport[ item.type.toLowerCase() ] ) {
    console.log("Item Type:" + item.type + " PASSED TEST");
  } else {
    console.log("Item Type:" + item.type + " FAILED TEST");
  }
});
```

If you wanted to stick with the way you started with then you want to use some brackets to better control the order or opperations.

```js
//tells if type should be included in the row data
isInReport = {factual: true, eac: false, variance: false}

//report has hundreds of objects, each with a type of either Plan, Factual, EAC, Variance
report = [{type: "Plan"}, {type: "Factual"}, {type: "EAC"}, {type: "Variance"}];

report.forEach(function(item){
  if (
    item.type === "Plan" ||
    item.type === (isInReport.factual ? "Factual" : "Plan") ||
    item.type === (isInReport.eac ? "EAC" : "Plan") ||
    item.type === (isInReport.variance ? "Variance" : "Plan")
  ) {
    console.log("Item Type:" + item.type + " PASSED TEST");
  } else {
    console.log("Item Type:" + item.type + " FAILED TEST");
  }  
});
```

Comment: Doesn't sound like it from the question, no; each type in `isInReport` correlates to two different string values allowed in the `item.type`.

Comment: @DaveNewton What use case does it fail on?

Comment: Thanks, this does seem to work, it should only pass for "Plan" and "Factual" since "plan" always passes and factual is "true" in the isInReport object

Comment: @JonSG I think none--I misunderstood the original logic's intent with the ternaries. I had thought that each type in `isInReport` defined multiple things that should be included, where in fact it's just duplicating the `"Plan"` check. It's rough to think about.

Comment: @DaveNewton, no worries.  I was an honest question on my part.  I was not sure I understood the problem.  Looks like I did in the end :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the error... i fiddle it up here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lnkky0fw/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var isInReport = {factual: true, eac: false, variance: false};

//report has hundreds of objects, each with a type of either Plan, Factual, EAC, Variance
var report = [{type: "Plan"},{type: "Factual"},{type: "EAC"},{type: "Variance"}];

report.map(function (item) {
  if (
  item.type === "Plan" ||
  item.type === (isInReport.factual) ? "Factual" : "Plan" ||
  item.type === (isInReport.eac) ? "EAC" : "Plan" ||
  item.type === (isInReport.variance) ? "Variance" : "Plan"
  ) {
   //do stuff
   alert('ok');

  }
});
});
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm getting. It should only alert for item.type === "Plan" and "Factual", but it alerts for all 4 types.

Comment: Humm it seems you need to organize your IF statement as this:

if (
    (item.type === "Plan") ||
    (item.type === ((isInReport.factual) ? "Factual" : "Plan")) ||
    (item.type === ((isInReport.eac) ? "EAC" : "Plan")) ||
    (item.type === ((isInReport.variance) ? "Variance" : "Plan"))
  ) {

http://jsfiddle.net/6mp0b1wm/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing commas between elements in your 'report' array.

Comment: Pretty sure that's a typo made while reducing the original source code to a manageable size.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create an array of the allowed values, then use filter. That will make it much easier to read and maintain than a multiple nested if/ternary mixture.

```js
var isInReport = {
    factual: true,
    eac: false,
    variance: false
};

var report = [{ type: "Plan" }, { type: "Factual" }, { type: "EAC" }, { type: "Variance" }];

var allowed = ["plan"]
    .concat(Object.keys(isInReport)
    .map(function (key) {
        if (isInReport[key]) return key.toLowerCase();
    }).filter(function (v) {
        return v;
    })
);

var filtered = report.filter(function (d) {
    if (allowed.indexOf(d.type.toLowerCase()) > -1) return true;
    return false;
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: This is a really interesting way to do this, and using functional techniques, I think this will work, never thought to do it that way

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose the ternary expressions in parentheses to obtain the expected result

```
if (
  item.type === "Plan" ||
  item.type === ((isInReport.factual) ? "Factual" : "Plan") ||
  item.type === ((isInReport.eac) ? "EAC" : "Plan") ||
  item.type === ((isInReport.variance) ? "Variance" : "Plan")
  )
```

(and you forgot the commas in

`report = [{type: "Plan"},{type: "Factual"},{type: "EAC"},{type: "Variance"}];`)